# Some cool things i can do with RAM??

Tags: programming, ram

What are some cool (technical) things i can do with RAM (500mb,ddr2)? I have it but cant't think of anything to do.

Comment: There is basically nothing cool you can do with SDRAM. The controller required is complex enough that it's almost unusable without.

Answer (score 6):

You could de-solder the chips, boil them in acid, make photos of the resulting dies like [ZeptoBars](http://zeptobars.ru/en/)

Unfortunately DRAM chips are very boring in that respect as they're just a huge matrix of small capacitors.